# Set ImageView to URL in android fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want my `imageView` to be able open the `url/link` when user clicks it. I searched some example but mostly it's not suitable for fragment. Can anyone help me?

`HomeFragment.java`

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

{


public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    ImageView img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTwitter);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIG);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ImageView img3 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFB);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;


}}
```

`fragmnet_main.xml`

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.eventstory.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/homepage" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewIG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/instagramlogo"

    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTwitter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewIG"
    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewFB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewIG"
    android:src="@drawable/logofacebook" />
```

The only `ImageView` working is `imageViewTwitter` but it link to facebook.com not twiiter. The other `ImageView` is not working

Comment: Where is click listener for ImageView?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I don't know how to correctly implement it.

Comment: Please show how you have implemented previously then we will suggestion

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have edited my post, please help.

Comment: What happening when clicking on ImageView?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Only one `ImageView` is working but it link to false url

Comment: Hey Danny post your complete fragment_main.xml  i think that you need set a listener to open an url for several buttons, right?

Comment: @Elenasys I update my xml code just now. Yes, I need those 3 `ImageView` to link in different site.

Comment: Check my answer, your problem is that you are assigning the onClickListeners to the same ImageView instance (img)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must be enough with:

```
...
...
      ImageView img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTwitter);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com"));
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);    
            }
        });

        ImageView img2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIG);
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"));
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageView img3 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFB);
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.gmail.com"));
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
...
...
```

Your problem is that you are assigning the `onClickListeners` to the same ImageView (img)!

```
  ImageView img2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIG);
  img.setOnClickListener...

  ImageView img3 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIG);
  img.setOnClickListener...
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, must missed that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used to open a **link/url** in browser.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.gmail.com"));
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

the reason behind that `startActivity()` is not working in a fragment because it is written in for `Activity` not for fragment. to be able to call this function you need to get the context of this application

> Example :

```
getApplictionContext().startActivity("call your relevant intent");
```